# Animações em alta qualidade

Tags: javascript, css3, ecmascript-6

Todos sabemos que as animações na web são um bem pouco amigáveis aos olhos, ao abrir um menu lateral, seja em `mobile` ou em `desktop`, você só consegue ver parte da sua movimentação, dando a impressão de um componente estático sem 'vida', pior ainda se comparado a animações de aplicações em `android`, `ios` etc...

Porém a web hoje já fornece várias soluções para isso, a mais engajada no momento é o [popmotion](https://popmotion.io/), com componentes e animações de alta qualidade, exemplo...

**[Codepen](https://codepen.io/popmotion/pen/LeZvXB)**

Gostaria de saber, como é possível esse tipo de efeito nas animações, qual a modificação `css` ou `js` que permite o controle de `fps` e a fluidez nos componentes? e se possível, o impacto desse tipo técnica para o futuro das aplicações.

Comment: Boa leitura! https://css-tricks.com/comparison-animation-technologies/

Comment: Oi Felipe. Eu removi a tag [tag:ux] porque a sua pergunta trata apenas tangencialmente do assunto. Ela é mais sobre como implementar as animações do que o porque delas existirem de forma x ou y. Outra dica é: cuidado com textos como "Todos sabemos que ....". Não é necessariamente uma verdade e pode soar pedante (principalmente se o leitor realmente não sabe o que vc diz que todos sabem). :)

Comment: Obrigado pela dica Luiz!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As animações Web não são necessariamente pouco amigáveis. As animações que fazem uso de CSS animations, ou outros truques CSS, são excelentes.

O que fica meio ruim são aquelas animações no estilo jQuery, pois são 100% baseados em código Javascript manipulando parâmetros básicos como x e y, mas foi algo criado numa época em que o CSS era muito mais fraco, e era melhor do que nada. Muita gente ainda usa porque é compatível com browsers antigos, e principalmente porque é facinho/há exemplos abundantes.

Quando você usa um computador (que pode ser um celular), na verdade está usando dois: um com CPU e outro com GPU. Via de regra os elementos gráficos são traçados na CPU, e depois transferidos para a GPU como uma textura. Essa transferência custa tempo e recursos.

As melhores animações são as que transformam a textura sem modificá-la, como é o caso de muitas animações CSS, porque elas vão como instruções para a GPU. As piores animações são as que redesenham um elemento, porque envolve trabalho para a CPU e também uma transferência para a GPU. A "fronteira de desenvolvimento" dos browsers é permiir manipulação da DOM diretamente na GPU, mas via de regra mexer na DOM cai no pior caso.

Comment: Boa resposta. Mas.... vc não quis dizer o contrário? "Via de regra os elementos gráficos são traçados na CPU, e depois transferidos para a GPU como uma textura." :)

Comment: Não, acho que foi isso mesmo. Gera usando CPU, transfere para a GPU. O ideal, e a tendência mesmo, é gerar na própria GPU, o novo engine do Firefox tenta transferir o máximo de trabalho para a GPU. Naturalmente, aplicativos 3D e jogos produzem todas as imagens na GPU.